# Working with money in android app

Tags: java, android

Hello my app is working with money. What structure i should use and how ?

I mean that from web service i get decimal number price. 
I don't do any operations with this money, no calculating. Can i keep this in String and when time comes to pass this price to bank ? Nothing would happens. Can i lose in this way some numbers ?

At some time i need to give this money using Intent and extras. Or i should use some other structure ? I appreciate for your help guys.

So give me your ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the BigInteger class introduced in Java, but not sure if you could easily send it between Activities.

Answer (score 0):

One reliable way to deal with currencies in Java and databases is to multiply the amounts by 100 and to use integers for operation. This way you won't be losing cents in various floating point conversions. Of course when you need to discharge the amount to a 3rd party you will need to divide back by 100.